# Updating a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpfdatagrid

I have a grid that contains an elapsed time column and I would like for the grid to be updated once per second.

```
private ObservableCollection<ACEvent> _acEvents
public ObservableCollection<ACEvent> AcEvents
    {
        set
        {
            _acEvents = value;
            PendingEventsGrid.ItemsSource = _acEvents;
            ElapsedTimer.Start();
        }
    }

public UI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ElapsedTimer.Tick += ElapsedTimer_Tick;
        ElapsedTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,1);
        _acEvents = new ObservableCollection<ACEvent>();
    }

void ElapsedTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var acEvent in _acEvents)
            {
                acEvent.Elapsed = DateTime.Now - acEvent.Timestamp;
            }

            PendingEventsGrid.Items.Refresh();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {}            
    }

<DataGrid Name="PendingEventsGrid" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="300,136,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="174" Width="135">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Elapsed" Binding="{Binding Elpased}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Event" Binding="{Binding EventDescription}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>    
    </DataGrid>
```

The 'Event' column populates as it should from _acEvents, but the 'Elapsed' column never has anything in it.

What am I missing here?

Comment: does your `ACEvent` class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and properly send property change notifications when the elapsed time updates?  Using `ObservableCollection` only updates the grid when items are added/removed, not when individual properties inside the objects change (that's what INPC is for)

Comment: have you tried actually Starting the timer in the Init() method instead of on your property set?

Comment: @JohnGardner It does not, and I didn't really expect it to update itself when the property changed, that is why I call Refresh() on the grid afterward... to force it to show the new value.

Comment: @MaxOvrdrv The timer is running for sure, I can put a break in the handler and see it catch every second.

Comment: Argh! Found the problem...  look at the binding of the Elapsed column...  I mis-spelled 'Elapsed'! I liked the INotifyProperyChanged suggestion tho, so I implemented that instead of using Items.Refresh().